# Backbone: Can't remove a view when call method remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have tried to remove a view that contains makers that are rendered in map. When I click a button, the event `click .ver` is being activated, but nothing happens and I receive the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
ev.views.Home_Eventos = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(map){
        this.template = _.template(ev.templateLoader.get('home_list_eventos'));
        this.map = map;
        //console.log(this.map);
        this.render(this.map);
    },

    events: {
        'click .ver' : 'teste'  
    },

    teste: function(){
        ev.views.Markers.remove();
    },

    render: function(map){
        var that = this;
        that.map = map;
        var imagens = new ev.models.ImagemCollection();
        imagens.fetch({
            success: function(){
                that.$el.html(that.template({imagens: imagens.models}));
                var marcadores = imagens.models;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    that.local(that.map);
                    var marcadores = new ev.views.Markers(that.map);
                }, 0);
                return that;
            }
        });
    }

});

ev.views.Markers = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(map){
        this.map = map;
        this.render(this.map);
    },

    render: function(map){
        var that = this;
        var imagens = new ev.models.ImagemCollection();
        imagens.fetch({
            success: function(){
                var marcadores = imagens.models;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    _.each(marcadores, function(marcador){
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marcador.get('latitude'),marcador.get('longitude'));
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            map: that.map,
                        });

                    });
                }, 0);

                return that;
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to delete `this` when I paste the code. Already edited.

Comment: `ev.views.Markers` refers to a class, not an actual `view` to be removed, which is likely _part_ of your problem. That `setTimeout` block with shadowed variables is not great either, but I don't think it's the issue.

Comment: Ok, I change to this: `marcadores.remove();` where `marcadores` is defined in method `render()`. But still doesn't work. The `setTimeout` was a way to rendering the markers in map, but it's not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the views you want to remove. For example, you have:

```
var marcadores = new ev.views.Markers(that.map);
```

you could save a reference on your view by doing this instead:

```
that.marcadores = new ev.views.Markers(that.map);
```

and then in your event handler,

```
teste: function(){
    this.marcadores.remove();
},
```

This will destroy the `Marker` view that you've created but may not clean up the Google Maps markers managed by that view.

Comment: I say _may not_ because I believe the markers get attached to the map. If this does clean them up, done deal. If it doesn't, you'll have to add a cleanup method to your `Markers` view to remove the markers from the map.

Comment: the markers are not removed, so I have to do what you said. Thank you for your suggestion and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the following:

```
ev.views.Markers = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
```

You are creating a new class. In order for `ev.views.Markers.remove();` to work correctly `ev.views.Markers` needs to refer to an *instance* of a class rather than the class itself.

You're getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` because `ev.views.Markers.remove` is not a function, `ev.views.Markers.prototype.remove` is.

Comment: I following your suggestion and I put `ev.views.Markers.prototype.remove` in my code, but still doesn't work :/

Comment: You've identified the problem but not the solution.

Comment: Fair enough. I believe I did identify the solution; to use an instance rather than a class. I didn't write the solution for the OP, but I did identify it.